# how to get rid of pop up on galaxy s4

Tags: clash-of-clans

I need to get rid of the Clash of Clans pop up. Every time I am on the phone talking, my cheek touches the screen and the games begins. I don't use my phone to play any games but my grandkids came during summer vacation and used my phone.

Comment: If you don't need the app anymore, just remove it.

Comment: or move the app button out of your main screen

Answer (score 2):

1.Go to Settings

2.Select applications

3.Select clash of clans

Select the option that says Disable Notifications.